# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm causing django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, html, django

So I see a lot of questions about the infamous "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." yet I cannot find anyone solving my problem as it doesn't have anything to do with my INSTALLED_APPS and it only goes away when I comment out the UserCreationForm.I am trying to create a basic signup page and UserCreationForm is the best way to do that. So does anyone know what I need to do to fix this? My lack of knowledge of this situation and of Django doesn't seem to help either but this seems as if it is a simple fix. Thank you for the help :).

**Here is all code I believe is relevant.**

**In settings.py**

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello.views',]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from hello.views import myView
from hello.views import myHome
from hello.views import home
from hello.views import index
from hello.views import game
from hello.views import main
from hello.views import signup
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import url, include
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/',include('hello.urls')),
    path('sayHello/', myView),
    path('home/',home,name='Home'),
    path('game/',game,name="Game"),
    path('home/game.html',game),
    path('home/home.html',home),
    path('game/game.html',game),
    path('game/home.html',home),
    path('main/',main),
    path('signup/',signup, name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name= 'login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name= 'logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
#from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
#from .models import Question

memo = []
def myView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, Surya!')

def myHome(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is going to be the main page.")
def home(request):
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    name = 'Jeevan Anand'

    args = {'myName': name, 'numbers': numbers}
    return render(request,'home.html',context = args)
def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')
def game(request):
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    name = 'Jeevan Anand'

    args = {'myName': name, 'numbers': numbers}
    return render(request,'game.html',context = args)
def main(request):
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    name = 'Jeevan Anand'

    args = {'myName': name, 'numbers': numbers}
    return render(request,'main.html',context = args)
def signup(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,'hello/signup.html',{'form':form})

def login_view(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #log in the user
            return redirect('articles:list')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'hello/login.html',{'from':form})
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `'hello.views'` as the app, it should just be `'hello'` (the app containing models.py, views.py, etc...).

Comment: 100% agree with @dirkgroten. if you're confused here, you can read it in [official dajngo docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models)

Comment: Thank you so much that was exactly my error I see now I was only loading in the hello.views app not all available apps.